How do I structure my tables and relationships in this scenario
I have 2 tables that are related using a junction table. Tbl_Items is basic information needed to create an internal "stock number" and to record info about what asset it came from. The Listings table records all the information from the listing once it is created
The current simplified tables are as follows:
Tbl_Items



ID_ItemsPK - AutoNumber
CategoryShort Text
Item numberShort Text
Short_DescriptionShort Text
AssetShort Text




979
Motorcycle
0123456789
Kawasaki Vulcan VN 750 87-06 OEM Center Stand 34011-1126
16 - Kawasaki 1993 Vulcan 750 - VN750 -



Tbl_Listings



ID_ListingsPK - AutoNumber
ID_ItemsNumber
Item numberShort Text
TitleShort Text
Start priceCurrency
Start dateDate/Time Extended
MakeShort Text
ModelShort Text
Part NumberShort Text




1243
979
0123456789
Kawasaki Vulcan VN 750 87-06 OEM Center Stand 34011-1126
$49.00
Aug-25-22 11:24:30 PDT
Kawasaki
Vulcan
34011-1126



Tbl_Import_Active_Listings



Item numberShort Text
TitleShort Text
Start priceNumber
Start dateShort Text
MakeShort Text
ModelShort Text
Part NumberShort Text




0123456789
Kawasaki Vulcan VN 750 87-06 OEM Center Stand 34011-1126
49
Aug-25-22 11:24:30 PDT
Kawasaki
Vulcan
34011-1126



The current work flow is as follows

Manually entry of the Item
Create listing with provider tools and post it live. A unique item number is created by the provider at that point
Manually enter the item number into the Items table and the Listings table
Finally, manually enter the lisiting details back into the listings table

At the moment step 3 is limited in detail because of the time it takes.  But capturing all of the listing data is important to streamline future listings.
I was advised to use a junction table and remove the Item Number from the Items table to not only prevent duplicate data in tables, but to prepare for a time where a many to many relationship would likely exsist between Items and Listings.
To test this I created the following junction table and removed the Item_Number from the Items table
Tbl_Junction_Items_Listings



ID_Items PK
ID_Listings PK




Joined On
Joined On


Tbl_Items.ID_Items
Tbl_Listings.ID_Listings



I'm not sure the junction table is appropriate in this case because as I see it there is really only a one to many relationship between Items (one) and Listings (many)
Ultimately I need to know if I'm missing something about the need for the junction table.
Most importanly, if I do need the Junction table, then how do I associate the listing back to the item when importing if I don't keep the item number is both tables
UPDATES:
I also have an Orders table which does require a many to many relationship with the Listings table. Would that be the reason it was suggested to use one for listings and items?
An Item can have multiple Listings when they are listed with multiple providers.
Consequently the Item Number for each listing will be different for each provider.
That's why I'm not sure how to match them up when I import them at day end

A listing can exist with multiple providers.  The other thing I forgot to clarify is that the Item Number is different for each provider. That's why Im not sure how to match them up when I import them at end of the day

Regardless of what ID provider assigns, you need your own identifier for item and it needs to be in the provider listing somehow. I see too much duplication of data between these two tables. Like your other deleted question, this one is too broad, no code to analyze, and responses would be opinions.

A junction table is needed if and only if there is a many-to-many relationship between the two tables. We can't know if that's the case. -- As June wrote, all duplicated data columns should be deleted. To get all data together, you use a query with join(s).

Is Item Number the identifier assigned by provider? Is Tbl_Import_Active_Listings supposed to be the junction table? Still need to clarify relationship. If an item can associate with multiple listings and a listing can have multiple items, that is many-to-many and need junction table. Define "Provider". An item can be listed once for each provider? "Listing" and "Provider" sounds rather synonymous.

I am thinking a "Listing" is an association of Item with Provider. Each item listed with multiple providers and each provider can have multiple items - so that is many-to-many relationship.

You answered my question
